# I want to set text of CATextLayer on click of button. how can it be achieved?

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer, catextlayer

I made a `CALayer *sublayer` over the main view, then I added `CATextLayer` over `sublayer`.

Now I want to show text on the `CATextLayer` by clicking a button on my main view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the buttons action using `-[UIButton addTarget:selector:forControlEvents:]:`, then in that function set the `CATextLayer`s string property to either an `NSString` or an `NSAttributedString`.

I remind you that `CATextLayer` doesn't respect paragraph settings on attributed strings, so line height is kind of off and does not look so great.

Comment: i am not making button programatically, how to set button action in xib file.